# How to access variables declared inside a loop in c#

Tags: c#, .net, loops

In the below code i have declared an and then assigned it to z. [Please note this is a duplicate]

```
double an;

for(double z= Amt+Intrest; z>0; z-=MonthlyInstallment)
{
    an = z;
}
```

I want to access the `an` variable in the below loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Months; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(i + 1, MonthlyInstallment, MonthlyIntrest, MonthlyInstallment - MonthlyIntrest,//use the an variable here);
}
```

Comment: and what is your problem? Where is this loop located? Within the same method? Then it should work directly. If it´s another method, you surely have to provide the variable as parameter to the method containing the second loop.

Comment: Have you tried typing `an` in place of the `//use the an variable here`?  You already did a pretty good job in the prior example

Comment: Out of curiosity, what value do you expect _an_ to have when you enter the second loop?

Comment: @ MickyD if i use the an variable direct in that second loop it says variable unassigned.

Comment: @Steve variable ```an``` has values which i have calculated which will be shown inside a gridview.

Comment: it's not quite clear how your code is organised by the example given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot relate the two loops directly, because I assume that those have equal iterations.

A suggestion: You could calculate the value a the loop.

```
// start with the base value.
double an = Amt + Intrest;

for (int i = 0; i < Months; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(i + 1, MonthlyInstallment, MonthlyIntrest, MonthlyInstallment -MonthlyIntrest, an);

    // decrease an with the MonthlyInstallment
    an = an - MonthlyInstallment;
}
```